# Shell scripting - inputting 4 lines from the user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a question. I need to read the user input, but I need the user enter 4 lines. Everytime time user presses enter it terminates the read command, so I did read commands 4 times (not sure if this is correct) - I need help with this.
Also how do I output user's input into file? and that output needs to me 4 lines as well. Please see my script.
I appreciate any help.

```
1  #!/bin/bash


2  #Displaying user name, host name, time, and date

3  Time=`date +%r`
4  Date=`date +%m/%d/%Y`
5  echo "$USER is running this script on $HOST at $Time on $Date:"
6  echo""
7  echo  "Please enter 4 lines of text:  "
8  read line1
9  read line2
10 read line3
11 read line4
12 echo "I'm now putting the four lines you entered into a text file called \"mylines.txt\"..."
13 echo $line1\n $line2\n $line3 \n$line4 > lines.txt
14 echo""
15 echo "The lines you entered were:\n$line1\n$line2\n$line3\n$line4"
16 echo""
```

Comment: The repeated `read` command is ok. For writing to a file use `echo -e "$line1\n$line2\n..." > lines.txt` (without spaces) or repeated `echo $1 >lines.txt`, `echo $line2 >> lines.txt` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read 4 lines you can use a loop and store it in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=()
echo  "Please enter 4 lines of text:  "
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
   IFS= read -p "Enter line $i: " -r line && lines+=("$line")
done
```

Then to print and redirect it:

```
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}" > lines.txt
```

Comment: When i try to run this, it tells me syntax error: "(" unexpected for `lines=()`

Comment: You're probably not using `bash` to execute it. Make sure you run this script using `bash ./script.sh`

Comment: So i cant run it as this `./script.txt` ? cuz this is how my professor wants it to do

Comment: Yes you can do that as well just use shebang `#!/bin/bash` at top of your script to make sure it runs with bash only

Comment: Nothing happens, it hits me with `syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103208/discussion-between-anubhava-and-anastasia-netz).

Comment: [Here is a working demo of above command](http://ideone.com/Vwevl2) and what happens when you enter command `type bash` in your terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a get what you want...
but see this peace of code

```
#!/bin/bash

myfile="file"

echo "a line im my file" > $myfile
echo "now a erased my file and create another with the same name" > $myfile
echo "now I'm writing at the end of my file" >> $myfile
echo "



now I put some lines in the end of my file" >> $myfile
```

if what you want is to put some lines into your file you may do:

```
echo $line1 > lines.txt
echo "



" + $line2 >> lines.txt
echo "



" + $line3 >> lines.txt
echo "



" + $line4 >> lines.txt
```

if it's only that, this sould do ;)